# French visa was denied

Tags: schengen, france, visa-refusals

> The reason was justification provided regarding purpose and conditions of your trip are not considered reliable

I submitted all documents properly with a French citizen’s sponsor letter.

I am going to my brother’s wedding in Saint Vallier, France.

Again my brother and mother-in-law going to get sponsor letter from the French council for me.

Can I apply for a French visa again?